# Property does not exist on type after type check

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typechecking

In the following code, I am trying to work with an instance of class Test after a type check.

**main.ts**

```js
class Test {
    x: number = 0;
    test() {}
}

let t1: Test | number = new Test();

if (t1 instanceof Test) {
    console.log(t1.x); // works
    let t2 = new Test();
    t2.test = function() {
        this.x = t1.x; // doesn't work
    }
}
```

After running `tsc main.ts` I get:

```
main.ts:12:21 - error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'number | Test'.
  Property 'x' does not exist on type 'number'.

12         this.x = t1.x; // doesn't work
                       ~


Found 1 error.
```

`tsc --version` returns `Version 3.4.5`

Comment: https://jsbin.com/yipezefoqa/1/edit?js,console — It works when I test it. (and `tsc main.ts` runs without errors when I try it on a local command line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that the `t1` is defined with `let`, it means in the runtime, when the `test` function on `t2` is called, it could have been already changed and not been of type `Test` anymore (well, not in the snippet, but from the compiler point of view, you can write some code after the function definition).

If you change the definition to `const`, it works fine:

```
class Test {
    x: number = 0;
    test() {}
}

const t1: Test | number = new Test();

if (t1 instanceof Test) {
    console.log(t1.x); // works
    let t2 = new Test();
    t2.test = function() {
        this.x = t1.x; // works fine
    }
}
```